# $f(x,y)= (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$. Show $f$ is one-to-one

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $A:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R},x>0\}$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $f(x,y)= (x^2-y^2, 2xy$). Show that $f$ is one-to-one on $A$.

### My attempt:

$$f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$$ so
$$\tag{$*$} x_1^2-y_1^2=x_2^2-y_2^2$$

and
$$2x_1y_1=2x_2y_2$$
$$\tag{$**$}x_1y_1=x_2y_2$$

From $(**)$, we have two cases. Either $y=0$ or $y\neq 0$.

CASE $1$ : $y=0$. From $(*)$: $$x_1^2=x_2^2$$ Taking the square root of both sides $$x_1=x_2$$ where $x_1,x_2>0$.

CASE $2$: $y \neq 0$

I am stuck on Case $2$...

Comment: Does it help to notice that $f$ is just the square function on $\mathbb{C}$ identified with $\mathbb{R}^2$ through $(x,y)\mapsto x+iy$?

Comment: What do you mean by $y\ne0$? Do you mean $y_1\ne0$ _and_ $y_2\ne0$? If so, then $y_1=y_2=0$ is not the only alternative, since you could have $y_1=0\ne y_2$ or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y)= (x^2-y^2, 2xy)
$.

If
$f(x, y) = f(u, v)$
then
$x^2-y^2 = u^2-v^2$
and
$2xy = 2uv$.

Squaring these,
$x^4-2x^2y^2 + y^4 = u^4-2u^2v^2+v^4$
and
$4x^2y^2 = 2u^2 v^2$,

Adding these,
$x^4+2x^2y^2 + y^4 = u^4+2u^2v^2+v^4$
or
$(x^2+y^2)^2 = (u^2+v^2)^2$.

Since both $x^2+y^2$
and
$u^2+v^2$
are positive,
we can take the square root
to get
$x^2+y^2 = u^2+v^2$.

Since
$x^2-y^2 = u^2-v^2$,
adding these we get
$2x^2 = 2u^2$;
subtracting them we get
$2y^2 = 2v^2$.

Therefore
$x^2 = u^2$
and
$y^2 = v^2$.

Therefore $x = \pm u$
and
$y = \pm v$.

By assumption
(on $A$),
$x \ge 0 $ and $u \ge 0$.

Therefore
$x = u$.

Since
$2xy = 2uv$,
$y = v$.

If you allow $x < 0$,
this is equivalent to
the two-valued nature of
the complex square root.

Comment: How did you square and then add?

Comment: Also, how did u jump to the conclusion that $x^2=u^2$ and $y^2=v^2$ ?

Comment: I'll expand my answer.

Comment: awesome! you made a small typo. $4x^2y^2=4u^2v^2$

Answer (score 2):

A slick way of approaching this is as follows. If $z =x+iy$, then 
$$ z^2 = (x^2-y^2) + 2xyi$$
so you function assigns a complex number $z = (x,y)$ to its square. But the square roots of $z\neq 0$ are two, and if $w$ is one, the other is $-w$. Now only one of $w$ has positive real part, so $z\longmapsto z^2$ is injective on $\Re(z) > 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Any other way to do this? I feel like if such question was on a test, I would not have been able to come up with this type of thinking.